# Save the data of forms to console in angular 2 - on click of save button

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Need help, to save the data to console in angular 2 application.

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/SMKu1SYHDd9ANbQfCZYH?p=preview)**

Whole data, tabs and respective information i am loading from json.

i have complex json format, but here i have made simplied version.

**Issue :** On **click of save button** unable to **save the data in console as a json format**.

**Expected:** Save the data in each respected fields (checkbox, textbox )values and output it in the console.log once **save button is clicked**, later i will be sending this data to server.

**Please note:** I tried with class and inheritance, but nothing is working for me.

[image]
Any help is appreciated, i am trying from one week.

**Json**

```
[
  {
    "id": "tab1",
    "name": "Tab 1",
    "wrapper": [
      {
        "header": "Header goes here",
        "content": [
          {
            "name": "Label 1",
            "id": "tab_1_Type",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "errorType": "green",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "Label 2",
            "id": "tab_1_Id",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "errorType": "red",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "header": "Comments",
        "content": [
          {
            "id": "tab_1_Id",
            "type": "textarea",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "tab2",
    "name": "Tab 2",
    "wrapper": [
      {
        "header": "Header goes here",
        "content": [
          {
            "name": "Text 1",
            "id": "tab_2_Type",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "errorType": "red",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "Text 2",
            "id": "tab_2_Id",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "errorType": "green",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "header": "Comments",
        "content": [
          {
            "id": "tab_2_Comments",
            "type": "textarea",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component,ContentChildren,QueryList, OnInit, Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {TAB_COMPONENTS} from './tabset';
import {Tab} from './tab';
import { DashboardService } from './app-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

<div class="col-md-12  pb-2 pt-4">
  <form class="form-horizontal">

<tabset>
  <tab *ngFor="let tab of records" [title]="tab.name"> 
  <div *ngFor="let wrapper of tab.wrapper">
    <div style="text-decoration:underline">{{wrapper.header}}</div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;" *ngFor="let name of wrapper.content">
      <label>
        <div [style.background]="name.errorType" style="height:12px; width:12px;display:inline-block "></div>
        <!-- Render checkboxes only if type === checkbox for comment boxes-->
        <input style="display:inline-block" *ngIf="name.type==='checkbox'"  name="{{name.id}}" type="{{name.type}}"> {{name.name}}    
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let name of wrapper.content">
      <!-- Render label only if type === textarea for comment boxes-->
      <textarea  class="col-md-12" *ngIf="name.type==='textarea'" name="{{name.id}}"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
<button class=" btn btn-primary " href="# " (click)="save() ">Save</button>

</form>
</div>`
})
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  records = [];
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(@Inject(DashboardService) private _dashboardService: DashboardService) {
    //this.getRecords();
  }

  // getting json values from report.json
  // To build the form
  ngOnInit() {
    this._dashboardService.getRecords()
      .subscribe(
        resGetRecords => {
          debugger;

          this.records = resGetRecords

        },
        resRecordsError => this.errorMsg = resRecordsError
      );
  }

    save(): void {
    console.log(this.error);
  }
}
```

Comment: why u r showing `this.error` ?

Comment: Hi, i want to save the data in 'error object' so it can be send to server

Comment: this doesn't exist in your plunker link

Comment: this.error does not exist in your component ...your question and your code doesnt even match .Please align your question and the code and rephrase your question

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it. @Vikhyath Maiya

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: no errors i am getting now, because i am not using error as a object in promise, mentioned here what i have tried.

Plunker is the one i have now, please help me if you can give any suggestions.

Comment: I have updated the post as well, i mentioned what i have tried, and what is exist in the plunker link, please check @Vikhyath Maiya

Comment: just try console.log(response,json()) and see if its printing the json ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156475/discussion-between-manjunath-siddappa-and-vikhyath-maiya).

Comment: seems to be working fine ..https://plnkr.co/edit/uyre4BG8ghv8Q518NG5P?p=preview

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Vikhyath Maiya.
Now i am getting as a json object but its not returning the values. for eg: checkbox, is it checked? comments content etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did some changes and it seems to be working now. Kindly check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZoHZ7B6EkdnDoSFrZJfX?p=preview)

Changes Done:

- Added `[checked] = "name.value" (change) = "name.value = !name.value"` to enable two way data-binding for Checkbox
- Added `[(ngModel)]="name.value"` to enable two way data-binding for Text-area
- Inside `save()` function, using `records` instead of `error`, as `records` is the variable that is used in template and hence it will be having the data-binding values

Updated **app.component.ts**:

```
import {Component,ContentChildren,QueryList, OnInit, Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {TAB_COMPONENTS} from './tabset';
import { Http, Response, Headers }     from '@angular/http';
import {Tab} from './tab';
import { Error } from './error';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { DashboardService } from './app.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

<div class="col-md-12  pb-2 pt-4">
  <form class="form-horizontal">

<tabset>
  <tab *ngFor="let tab of records" [title]="tab.name"> 
  <div *ngFor="let wrapper of tab.wrapper">
    <div style="text-decoration:underline">{{wrapper.header}}</div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;" *ngFor="let name of wrapper.content">
      <label>
        <div [style.background]="name.errorType" style="height:12px; width:12px;display:inline-block "></div>
        <!-- Render checkboxes only if type === checkbox for comment boxes-->
        <input style="display:inline-block" *ngIf="name.type==='checkbox'"  name="{{name.id}}" type="{{name.type}}" [checked] = "name.value" (change) = "name.value = !name.value"> {{name.name}} 
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let name of wrapper.content">
      <!-- Render label only if type === textarea for comment boxes-->
      <textarea  class="col-md-12" *ngIf="name.type==='textarea'" name="{{name.id}}" [(ngModel)]="name.value"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
<button type="button" class=" btn btn-primary " href="" (click)="save() ">Save</button>

</form>
</div>`
})
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  records = [];
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService, private http: Http) {
    this.getRecords();
   }

   // getting json values from configuration.json
   // To build the form
  ngOnInit() {
  this._dashboardService.getRecords()
      .subscribe(
      resGetRecords => this.records = resGetRecords,
      resRecordsError => this.errorMsg = resRecordsError
      );
  }

   // Error object from error.ts
  error: Error;
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private api = './app/report.json';

  // getting json values from report.json
   // To save the form
  getRecords(): Promise<Error[]> {
    console.log(this.api);
    return this.http.get(this.api)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
         response.json().data as Error[]
         this.error = response.json();
         console.log(this.error);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  // On click of save button show console log with values
  save(): void {
    console.log("Inside save");
    console.log(this.records);
  }
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); 
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }


}
```